# pynput via ssh want to monitor mouse movements

Tags: python, ssh, mouse, xvfb, pynput

Raspberry Pi4, Rasbian
Attached KB, Mouse, no monitor,
ssh'ing to device over Wifi vi putty

I'm brand new to Python, so struggling with some basics here.  And I think I have some advanced (to me) things with X muddying the waters.  If I could get over the hump and do anything simple I could probably take it from there.

For this "simple" example I want to monitor the mouse using pynput.  I want to output to my SSH terminal screen the connected mouse's position/movements as determined by pynput.  I was attempting to do that via the print command, using a code snippet from the pynput documentation.

I know the docs try to head me off this path of using ssh but they also say there is a workaround.  Form pnyput docs:

> On Linux, pynput uses X, so the following must be true:
>
> ```
> An X server must be running.
> The environment variable $DISPLAY must be set.
> ```
>
> The latter requirement means that running pynput over SSH generally
> will not work. To work around that, make sure to set $DISPLAY:
>
> $ DISPLAY=:0 python -c 'import pynput'

I gathered, to do this "headless" on this Pi, and per the docs above I needed to run a X server.  So I installed Xvfb.  I started Xvfb with

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1152x900x8&
```

(I did not use sudo)

I have my code in a file named mouse5.py.  The code reads:

```
print ("Ready")
    
from pynput import mouse

# The event listener will be running in this block
with mouse.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        if event.button == mouse.Button.right:
            break
        else:
            print('Received event {}'.format(event))
```

I attempt to run the code by entering:

```
pi@Raspberry4:~ $ DISPLAY=:99 python mouse8.py
```

I get the "Ready" printed out on my console.  But moving the mouse does nothing.

Can someone get me straightened out?  Figure I'm missing some simple detail from lack of python and X experience.